# Knowledge graph entities visualization

Tags: javascript, knowledge-graph

I am completely new to Knowledge graphs. I have a ttl file representing RDF data and I was doing a simple online user interface.

As soon as a user clicks on an entity I would like him to go to a new page and show the associated objects.

This is how I am representing an entity:

```
<a onclick=\"per(event);\" href=\""+contents[0]+"\">"+contents[1]+"</a>"
```

where `contents[0]` has the URI of a person ex: http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person13538

while `contents[1]` has the name of the person.

I would like that `onclick` I get a new tab with the results of the ajax query where it matches the URI.

Comment: Please give us some more information about how your web pages are generated.  Are you using a server?  An SPA?  Are you wanting to do this purely with JavaScript?

Comment: I am using an Apache Fuseki server to query the data